# Reputation without any posts

Tags: discussion, reputation

I recently came across this profile:

[image: preview]

Is it a special request for some users to have reputation without having to post? Or, what happened to that profile? I could see that the profile owner is a biggie (Community Manager for Google Search).

How does this work?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/571557/kelly-f) is not a Community Manager, well at least not someone employed by Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Glorfindel Guessed it.

Comment: @Glorfindel It's easy to check if the profile's email address matches with `google.com` or similar domains, coz that's what Google's staff are provided with, but yea, not our headache. `;)`

Comment: Worth to mention that we can see the time of upvotes in the [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/571557/kelly-f?tab=reputation), though expanding the days won't show link to the deleted answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Exactly! Apparently there's no way we can find what are all the deleted posts as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pulling directly from [How does reputation works?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> Deleting and undeleting posts may reverse reputation effects as well, if these posts have votes. Actions previously taken on deleted posts cease to affect reputation within five minutes ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)), unless the post meets both the following criteria (in which case the reputation effects will be permanent) ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)):
>
> - The post had a score of at least +3
> - The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days

This particular account had an answer that was visible for 4 months with a score of 3, so they kept the reputation when the answer was deleted.

Comment: Ooh nice... I know about this. But just came to know that there are ill-effects like "No posts" on profile...

Comment: this explains the reputation of this post-less user, but in addition you should know it's possible to earn reputation by having suggested edits approved; this is another route to reputation with no questions or answers ever.

Comment: @KateGregory There wasn't any suggested edits as well. I know, anything and everything will be logged in the reputation. Right? And also, to note that when the posts that have been suggested are deleted, the associated reputation is removed as well.